# Re-using another page section

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a web page that I use as a small dashboard to hold issue or no issue.  It works great.  The page uses an .aspx and .aspx.cs.  I would like to be able to reuse the information on this page on other pages.  My site already uses master pages and I have not been able to find an easy way to include this information.

How can I use an include from a page that has coding in the code behind easily?

Comment: You really need to read more documentation!! Do you know what's a user or web control? :D

Comment: put all the markup and code to user control ( ascx ) and use it in all places needed

Comment: Folks he / she may not even be asking about user controls - it could be just a set of functions / methods that he would like to call from any web form.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you use [Web User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3457w616%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for this.

Web User Controls allow you to package up other controls into one that you can drop onto multiple pages.  They are great for common UI items such as address entries, dashboards, etc.  Basically anything that needs to be the same across multiple pages.

Comment: The user control sounds as an interesting option.  Let me review that in more detail now that I have a starting point.  I am a beginner and hardest part is figuring out exactly what to lookup.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of seeming very obvious - do you mean usercontrols. These will allow you to reuse chunks of functionality across your site.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this question falls into two categories: User Controls, and Code Reuse.  Not sure which one you are after.

**User Controls**

If you are talking about the controls on your page you will want to create a common user control.

---

**Code Reuse**

You need to create a common class (whether it is static or not depends on how you intend to use it) and define functions within that class.

For instance, lets say you have a page that you want to print "Hello World!" on any aspx/.cs page.

You could do this

```
public static class MyClass
 {
  public string PrintHelloWorld() 
    { 
      return "Hello World!";
    }
 }
```

Then you call it from any of your pages like so:

`MyClass.PrintHelloWorld();`

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project > Add New Item...

Select User Control (.ascx)

Put your markup & code behind there.

Then you add that control in any other page (includding other controls [although I wouldn't recommend that])

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may want to create an ascx User Control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/2x6sx01c.aspx

Comment: whoa not quick enough on the draw on that one ;)